# not sure how to interpret and solve ImportError from lxml using py2exe

Tags: python, exe, lxml, py2exe

I'm trying to build a standalone executable file from a python script using [py2exe](https://pypi.org/project/py2exe/)

The creation of the .exe file does not output any warning nor errors, but when i actually try to execute it from command prompt it outputs the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 259, in load_module
>
> File "", line 15, in
>
> File "", line 13, in __load
>
> ImportError: (cannot import name _elementpath) 'C:\CAD\Workspace\username\dev-env\dist\lxml.etree.pyd'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 259, in load_module
>
> File "", line 15, in
>
> File "", line 11, in __load
> ...
>
> File "", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
> File "", line 261, in load_module
>
> KeyError: 'lxml.objectify'

The call i use, in the div folder, is the following `mdf2mat.exe C:\CAD\username\usefulScripts\dev-folder\dosingFromCANape.mdf`

And this is the code of the script:

```
import mdfreader
import sys

fileIn = sys.argv[1]
mdfFile = mdfreader.Mdf(fileIn)
mdfFile.export_to_matlab()
```

and lastly, this is the code i use to create the .exe:

```
py2exe.freeze(console={"C:\CAD\Workspace\username\dev-env\mdf2mat.py"})
```

Now from the [list](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/WorkingWithVariousPackagesAndModules) of packages supported by py2exe, `lxml` has this remark:

> if missing _elementhpath, either pull whole lxml library in packages=..., or put "from lxml import _elementhpath as _dummy" somewhere in code; in both cases also pull gzip in packages=...

which describes exactly my situation.

Since i'm quite the beginner with this i have no idea what it means with 'pulling whole library in packages' or 'pull gzip in packages' hence i cannot solve the issue.

Comment: I would think the suggestion about `packages=` refers to setuptools/setup https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html where you can use the `packages=['package1','package2']` parameter to provide a list of packages.

Comment: as far as i understood the usage of setup tools is deprecated, quoting the docs `Using a setup.py script with py2exe is deprecated. Please adapt your scripts to use the new freeze API. This interface will be removed in the next major release.`

Comment: I am not familiar with details of the tool you use but check whether that freeze API has a similar `packages=` parameter.

Comment: it indeed does, under `options`. I'll try and let you know